# Need to set-up multiple Facebook Apps under one domain using subdirectories

Tags: facebook, iis, ssl, facebook-apps, virtual-directory

So I don't have to purchase SSL certs for every Facebook app I want to create, I am trying to set up multiple Facebook Apps under one domain using subdirectories.  So I set-up the root site directory using SSL under the domain example.com and the Facebook app works fine.  I am trying to set up a second Facebook app using example.com/app2.  So I set up a virtual directory in the root directory for example.com/app2 and that did not work.  Then I converted the virtual directory to a separate web application (clicked the "Convert to Web Application" option, and that did not work.  I am getting a 500 error within Facebook when I try anything as it's not recognizing that the subdirectory exists.  I am stumped on this one, any help is appreciated.